# Cron : Setting multiple minutes

Tags: cron

With cron, if I wanted to run a command every 5 mins it would be:

```
*/5 * * * * command
```

But what if I wanted to set a list of minutes specifically?

Like at 5 past, 18 mins past and 15 minutes too the hour?  I'm guessing this:

```
5,18,45 * * * *
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, the solution you specified is correct.

```
0,5,55 * * * * command       # run the command at the top of the hour, at
                             # the 5 minute mark and at the 55 minute mark.
```